# Bash store dbus output in array

Tags: arrays, bash, return-value, dbus

I would like to store a dbus output into an array.

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="com.ac.comp" /com/ac/comp/IO com.ac.comp.Time.Get
```

When I execute the above command, I obtain the following output :

```
method return sender=:1.191 -> dest=:1.198 reply_serial=2
   uint16 1
   uint16 0
   uint16 0
   uint32 0
```

I have implemented my bash as follow :

```
if [ -f $file ]                     
then
    IFS=".="                    
    while read enum name ID x                           
    do 
       if [ "$enum" == "IO" ] && [ "$name" == $IOname ]
       then 
       array=($(dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="com.ac.comp" /com/ac/comp/IO com.ac.comp.IO.Get uint16:16)) 
       fi
    done < $1                       
else
    exit_error 
fi
```

I can not explain why the following echo commands :

```
echo ${array[1]} 
echo
echo ${array[2]} 
echo 
echo ${array[3]} 
echo 
echo ${array[4]} 
echo 
echo ${array[5]}
echo
echo ${array[6]}   
echo
echo ${array[7]}
echo 
echo ${array[8]}   
echo
echo ${array[9]}
echo
echo ${array[10]}  
echo
echo ${array[11]}
echo 
echo ${array[12]}  
echo
echo ${array[13]}
```

gives

```
:1

105 -> dest

:1

112 reply_serial

2
   uint16 1
   uint16 0
   uint16 0
   uint32 0
```

I would like to reuse the uint16 and uint32 values. But I though retrieve them in ${array[7]} ${array[9]} ${array[11]} and ${array[13]}

Comment: What do you get if you pipe the `dbus-send` output into `hexdump` or `xxd`?

Comment: Sorry Etan, but how can I test these output

Comment: Hm? I was asking you to tell us what you get if you do that. So that we could see what the shell was seeing when it split the output into the array. Or did you mean how to do that? `dbus-send ... | xxd`

Comment: I just edited the main post. This is how the data are stored into the array. It is not a normal behavior ..

Comment: That is normal if your `IFS` is set to `.`.

Comment: !! You have probably found the issue. I edited once again my main post and I added the function implemented. I modify the IFS in order to realise the while loop on a text file.

Comment: Finally I just have to restore the default IFS at the good place .. isn't it ?

Comment: Yup, don't do that. `while IFS=. read ...` will change `IFS` for `read` only. But that doesn't work for other commands `read` is special that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've modified `IFS` so the shell is splitting on `.` instead of whitespace.

Don't do that.

`read` is special in that it can take a "local" value for `IFS` directly.

So instead of

```
IFS=.
while read ....; do
    ...
done
```

which modifies `IFS` for the entire shell you can do

```
while IFS=. read ....; do
    ...
done
```

and only modify `IFS` for the `read` built-in.

Comment: Thank Etan. Your solution works fine. I can also use IFS=$' \t\n' to restore the default IFS.

Comment: You could, you could also save `IFS` before you replace it and then restore *that* value but it is better to not mess with it globally in the first place.